# Check this game loop

Tags: java

below is a game loop i found on the internet. It works but its putting huge load on the CPU(60% to 70%) and the game also is a little sluggish! All the tweaks i made are working on that particular pc but when i try on different pc's it behaves completely different. At this pc i'm getting ~60tics and ~150fps.

```
public void run() {
        init();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            if(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }

            render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println(updates + " Ticks, Fps " + frames);
                updates = 0;
                frames = 0;
            }

        }
        stop();
    }
```

Comment: You may post that on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

put a `Thread.sleep` in your while loop

```
try {
Thread.sleep(50);
} catch(Exception e){
}
```

to add this, you slow down the fps. you should not use max fps. 24 fps is enough for most of the games.

Comment: Common PC games are often higher than 24 fps. You could put a high limit at 60 instead.

Comment: yes, it would be much better. I assume this code comes from a 2D games. for 2D games, 20-30 fps would be enough most of the times.

Comment: But 24 fps is more cinematic.